# Intellij 2017.3.5 emulator cannot launch

Tags: intellij-idea, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am having problem after I updated my sdk via intellij updates. my sdk resides in D:/sdk, now after updating when I launch the AVD and click triangular green button to lunch the emulator. Nothing happens no emulator is launching I don't know why.

[image]

Comment: Try reinstalling the SDK, check [the logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I will download again the sdk ?

Comment: Yes, also delete .avd directory in your user home to start over.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, nothing happen.

Comment: Try with https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/ or AS 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

It probably has something to do with ***virtualization***.
**Check if virtualization is enabled in the BIOS** setting of your machine. And if you're working **on Windows make sure "Hyper-V" options are disabled in "Windows Features"**.